# Finding best fitting universal weights for several weighted sums

Tags: linear-algebra

I have several weighted sum equations, all of the following form:

- $Sum1 = 0.6x + 0.4y$
- $Sum2 = 0.5x + 0.5y$
- $Sum3 = 0.2x + 0.8y$
- $Sum4 = 0.7x + 0.3y$
- $...$

I am searching for the best fitting pair of $x, y$ values, as no $x, y$ pair can solve all equations at once. The other values are known. It is also known that $x$ and $y$ are (should be) within the range $[0, 1]$.

So far I have tried some naive iterative approaches. Trying to close in on the optimal value by starting at an arbitrary pair, such as $0, 0$, and then altering the values in each step in a direction which reduces the total error. The problem is that I always seem to get stuck in a local optima, even when an accurate solution to the problem exists (on generated test data).

I am sure that the best fit values can be found reliably, but I don't know how to handle this problem best. Searching for best fits yielded lots of information for fitting various curve types to a set of data points, but that doesn't seem to trivially translate to this case, or at least I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look very much like a linear regression problem in two variables with no intercept
$$z=x \,a + y\, b$$ for a set of $n$ data points $(a_i,b_i,z_i)$ where $(x,y)$ are the coefficients to be dtermined.

Let us use just basic calculus and write each equation as $$s_i=a_i\, x+ b_i \,y$$ and consider the norm
$$\Phi=\frac 12\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i\, x+ b_i \,y-s_i)^2$$ and compute the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x}=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i (a_i\, x+b_i\, y-s_i)$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i (a_i\, x+b_i\, y-s_i)$$ Set them equal to $0$ and expand to get
$$x \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+y\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i$$
$$x \sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i+y\sum_{i=1}^n  b_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i s_i$$ So, two linear equations to be solved for $(x,y)$.

If, in all your equations, $a_i+b_i=1$ but this does not change the problem except thet the calculations are simpler since
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i -\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \qquad 
\sum_{i=1}^n  b_i^2=n-2\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \qquad 
\sum_{i=1}^n b_i s_i=\sum_{i=1}^n s_i-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i$$

For illustration purposes, let us use the few cases you posted
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 i & a_i & b_i & s_i \\
 1 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 3.0 \\
 2 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 2.9 \\
 3 & 0.2 & 0.8 & 2.8 \\
 4 & 0.7 & 0.3 & 3.0
\end{array}
\right)$$ and let us work withe whole numbers. This leads to

$$\frac{57}{50}x+\frac{43}{50}y=\frac{591}{100}$$
$$\frac{43}{50}x+\frac{57}{50}y=\frac{579}{100}$$ the solutions of which being
$$x=\frac{879}{280}\approx 3.13929 \qquad \text{and} \qquad y=\frac{759}{280}\approx 2.71071$$ and,to tell the truth, the numbers where generated using
$$s_i=\frac{\text{Round}[10 (\pi\,  a_i+e \,b_i)]}{10} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spend hours trying to solve this with what came to my mind intuitively. Usually that is enough, but not this time. I just implemented your suggestion and it works out very nicely.

Oh, and your observation was correct, e.g. the factors always sum up to 1.